# PhpMyAdmin not working on localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Xampp version:1.7.7 (installed it on external hard drive), operating system: Windows 8, 
installed version 4.1.7 of phpMyAdmin and copied config.inc.php from my old version of phpmyadmin to the new phpmyadmin version (4.1.7)

When I type localhost/phpMyAdmin I get the error message:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost 02/13/14 17:16:55 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32)
>   mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8

So I had a look in the xampp localhost welcome page http://pngwebdesign.co.uk/forum/localhost.jpg and in the security link **PhpMyAdmin**: Could not find the '`config.inc.php`' comes up, how can this be recified

Looked in my local phpmyadmin folder and the `config.inc.php` file is there so I really don't understand why I can't log into localhost/phpMyAdmin

Any help appreciated

Comment: Use lowercase 'phpmyadmin' in the url. If not resolved, check whether mysql service is started in your machine. Run services.msc from 'Run Command' and check mysql service.

Comment: also make sure, that not only your sql BUT ALSO your apache server is runnnig!

Answer (score 33):

All I had to do was load `localhost:80/phpmyadmin` and then the browser figured it out. After that, `localhost/phpmyadmin` worked.

Comment: Thanks! This saved my time, I think the accepted answer should add this step as well.

Comment: In my case it was 8080: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried both localhost:80/phpmyadmin and localhost:8080/phpmyadmin, a message from google chrome says, 

This site can't be reached

Localhost refused to connect

Thanks anyway David and Stephan

Answer (score 24):

did you try 'localhost/phpmyadmin' ? (notice the lowercase)

PHPMyAdmin tends to have inconsistent directory names across its versions/distributions.

**Edit:** Confirm the URL by checking the name of the root folder!

If the config was the primary issue (and it may still be nthary) you would get a php error, not a http "Object not found" error,

As for the config error, here are some steps to correct it:

1. Once you have confirmed which case your PHPMyAdmin is in, confirm that your config.inc.php is located in its root directory.
2. If it is, rename it to something else as a backup. Then copy the config.sample.inc.php (in the same directory) and rename it to config.inc.php
3. Check if it works.
4. If its does, then open up both the new config.inc.php (that works) and the backup you took earlier of your old one. Compare them and copy/replace the important parts that you want to carry over, the file (in its default state) isn't that long and it should be relatively easy to do so.

N.B.
If the reason that you want your old config is because of security setup that you once had, I would definitely suggest still using the security wizard built into XAMPP so that you can be assured that you have the right configuration for the right version. There is no guarantee that different XAMPP/PHPMyAdmin versions implement security/anything in the same way.

XAMPP Security Wizard

```
http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php
```

Comment: tried phpmyadmin in lowercase, still getting object not found also followed the instructions above, still getting object not found, apache and mysql works. stumped!!

Comment: fixed the problem, had the version number on the root folder

Comment: That's a new one, I will have to look out for that.

Comment: Good stuff, this worked for me. Odd thing is that the folder on the file system has some caps in it.

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much! This is ridiculous lol. I've been using xampp with 7.3 php. Tried to install the 7.1 and cant access the phpmyadmin therefore.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using ubuntu then try these command after installation of phpmyadmin

```
sudo cp /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf

sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Finally, I found a solution

Answer (score 6):

when I started xampp on my windows 10 there were many options available, unfortunately every one of them failed. I ll list them so that you don't go through all of them again.

### THINGS THAT DIDN'T WORK

1) i installed xampp initially in a different drive and not c because of UAC         issues so i uninstalled Xampp and installed it again in c (didn't work)
2) while reinstalling i deactivated the antivirus as setup said that some 
  installing might not end up properly(realized it doesn't matter :) lmao)
3) i tried to change ports several times of xampp from 80 to some different number like 8080 etc. still nothing happened 
4) i then tried using firefox  as it is believed that internet explorer or internet edge is not a good browser for xampp
5) after that i went to config file i.e config.inc inside phpmyadmin folder 
and did some crap as were given in the instructions. Failure it was
6) then i closed laptop and went to sleep(XD srry leave this point)
7)  then i tried searching for windows web services in the services.msc
to disable it. i couldn't find it

### WHAT WORKED

On eighth time i got success.This is what i did 
8)In control panel, where you have actions , modules PIDs, Ports you will see 
Services under which you will see gray boxes which are actually checkboxes but are empty initially. i checked it so that xampp services start and apache services start. now you will see them ticked.
  After that just change the port of xampp and apache to 80.

I hope it helps. cheers ;)

Comment: had the same problem, i just had to start apache as well. thank you

Comment: @Leajian, your comment should be an answer, because that what my solution xD

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix. (If you are using proxy on your network)
//Windows
1. Open control panel
2. Network and internet
3. Network and sharing center
4. On the bottom left side of the window, you will see Internet Options, under connections tab, click LAN settings check the bypass

Answer (score 1):

#### Prerequisites for running phpmyadmin:

1. Apache Service module is checked (box on the left most side)
2. Apache is running
3. Optional: might have to add the port in the url if the default 80/8080 is not available. (Ex. localhost:xxxx/phpmyadmin/). Control panel should show you the port being used (underlined blue)

[image]

#### Summary

You need Apache to run phpmyadmin. XAMPP does NOT start Apache for you automatically when you click on the "Admin" button.

#### Afterthought

XAMPP should disable the Admin button if Apache is not running or start it for you.


Note: Just started using XAMPP. Was a simple fix for my issue lol

Answer (score 0):

Try starting MySQL and Apache in Xampp. Verify Port Number assigned to Apache (By default it should be 80). Now load `localhost/phpmyadmin`. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same Object Not Found problem here - both in Xampp as well as in Wamp. It turns out the root name of "phpmyadmin" was "PhpMyAdmin". I got rid of all the capitals, renaming the folder to "phpmyadmin", and after a couple of reloads phpmyadmin was working.

Answer (score 0):

STOP ALL SERVICES OF XAMPP 
Edit Apache(httpd.conf) file 
1)"Listen 80"
 if its already 80  and not working then replace it by 81
2) "ServerName localhost:80"
if its already 80  and not working then replace it by 81
SAVE EXIT RESTART [WINDOWS USER run as administrator]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was getting the Object not found error as shown in the screen shot while clicking the phpmyadmin link. Apache and SQL server had got started from the xampp console.

Solution: I uninstalled and installed again after deleting all the files and folders of xampp from C drive. Also, this time, I installed just the Apache and the SQL server. After this, phpmyadmin link started to work.

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/error.php?lang=en&dir=ltr&type=Error&error=Cannot+load+%5Ba%40http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmysqli%40Documentation%5D%5Bem%5Dmysqli%5B%2Fem%5D%5B%2Fa%5D+extension.+Please+check+your+PHP+configuration.+-*****

Answer (score 0):

Try to navigate below URL .this workes to me
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I have mistake, i see in the xampp ui show MySQL port is 3306, i realize that i need to call request to phpmyadmin on 8080 por

```
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3306/phpmyadmin
```

[image]