# How to access phpmyadmin and the moodle user table in local database (Windows 8)

Tags: phpmyadmin, moodle

I am a newbie with moodle (a learning-management system).

I have installed moodle on my Windows 8 laptop.

I want to get access to the user table of moodle, using phpmyadmin. How do I do that?

Comment: It's usually http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: when i type localhost/phpmyadmin in browser, the browser respond : object not found

Comment: could be case sensitive - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748086/phpmyadmin-not-working-on-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed Moodle using `XAMPP` and you enter your moodle site with domain like

> http://localhost/mymoodlesite

So to enter the `phpMyAdmin` you have to write

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin

There you will see on the left side a list of databases and yours should be called for example `mymoodlesite`. Inside the database you will find different tables, be aware, that every table in `Moodle` starts with `mdl_`